# Hyperledger Caliper: fabric-remote test

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, remote-server, hyperledger-caliper

Version INFO:

Hyperledger Fabric: 2.2 /
Caliper: 0.4.2

Hi, All.
I have a already running blockchain network on the cloud developing instance. By the way, the caliper worked pretty good on the cloud server.

Now, I am trying to work remotely with the Caliper.

So the caliper will work on localhost and benchmarking the blockchain network that on the cloud.

However, I have researched for a while and got nothing yet.

Any recommendations will be welcomed!

Good day!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail such as what you have tried, what errors you get ? From your above information it's difficult to understand what problem you are facing

Comment: I have just researched how to test blockchain network remotely. But I couldn't find any details to conduct it. So I am facing the problem that finding instructions to do the remote caliper performance test between localhost and cloud server.

Comment: maybe this will help as a starting point ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605285/why-containerized-version-of-hl-caliper-is-always-trying-to-connect-to-localhost

Comment: I really appreciated. Thank you! I will try it out and let you know the result on this comment. =)